# How to [int]add in a [string]regex replacement in powershell?

Tags: powershell, replace, callback, delegates

I'm renaming files with a regex replacement:

```
ls *dat | rename-item -newname {$_.name -replace '(.*)_([0-9]+)(.dat)','$1($2)$3'}
```

but I want also to add a `constant int` to `[string]$2`; something like :

```
'$1(@{int.parse($2)+3})($3)'
```

How should I proceed ?

Comment: You need a [callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28178589/1630171) for that.

Comment: Another option (nice callback function comment above) is to use the `-match` operator: `'abc_123.dat' -match '(.*)_([0-9]+)(.dat)' | out-null;$matches[1] + "($(([int]::Parse($matches[2]) + 3)))" + $matches[3];`

Comment: i feel stupid reading this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**PowerShell *Core* v6.1.0+** supports **passing a *script block* as the replacement operand of the

`-replace` operator**; the script block is invoked for each match found, and its output forms the replacement string, thereby **enabling *algorithmic* replacements** (rather than merely *textual* ones):

```
'foo_10.dat' -replace '(.*)_([0-9]+)(\.dat)', { 
  '{0}{1}{2}' -f $_.Groups[1].Value, 
                 ([int] $_.Groups[2].Value + 3), 
                 $_.Groups[3].Value
}
```

The above yields:

```
foo13.dat
```

Note how `3` was added to `10` (and the underscore was removed):

`$_` inside the script block is a [`[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match) instance representing the results of the match; e.g., `$_.Value` represents the full match, whereas `$_.Groups[1].Value` represents what the 1st capture group matched.

The functionality is built on the [`[regex]` .NET type's `.Replace()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c.aspx), which can also used directly (but less easily) in earlier PowerShell versions - see below.

---

In ***Windows PowerShell*** you have two **options**:

- Use the `-match` operator first and then perform the transformation in a separate statement based on the match information reflected in the automatic `$Matches` variable, as suggested by [kuujinbo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/604196/kuujinbo):

  ```
  $null = 'foo_10.dat' -match '(.*)_([0-9]+)(\.dat)' # match first
  '{0}{1}{2}' -f $Matches.1, ([int] $Matches.2 + 3), $Matches.3 # build via $Matches
  ```
- Use the .NET framework directly, with a script block passed as a *delegate* (callback function) to the above-mentioned `[regex]::Replace()` method, as suggested by [Ansgar Wiechers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers):

  ```
  ([regex] '(.*)_([0-9]+)(\.dat)').Replace('foo_10.dat', {
    param($match)
    '{0}{1}{2}' -f $match.Groups[1].Value, ([int] $match.Groups[2].Value + 3), $match.Groups[3].Value
  })
  ```

  - Note how a formal parameter - `param($match)` - must be declared here in order to access the match results, whereas the pure PowerShell solution at the top was able to use `$_`, as usual.